# Maven tool of Java, what tool, bash script, method or command can list installed package name and version? or with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Maven tool of Java, what tool, bash script, method or command can list installed package name and version? or with maven.
have like this command `pip list` or easy method?

Comment: What exactly do you want? List the content of the local repository? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: List the content of the local repository

Comment: And what are you planning to do with this information?